# Angular 7 Crud webAPI -> compilation error after adding #form

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, angular7, webapi

Hi I have a problem with my project, everything works till I'm adding to employee.component.html form like this:

```
    <form #form="formData">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>FULL NAME</label>
            <input name="FullName" #FullName="ngModule" [(ngModule)]="service.formData.FullName" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </form>
```

***after this on may localhost I see error "filed to compile"***

**This is my app.module.ts**

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { EmpolyeesComponent } from './empolyees/empolyees.component';
    import { EmpolyeeComponent } from './employees/empolyee/empolyee.component';
    import { EmpolyeeListComponent } from './employees/empolyee-list/empolyee-list.component';
    import { EmpolyeeService } from './shared/empolyee.service';
    import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        EmpolyeesComponent,
        EmpolyeeComponent,
        EmpolyeeListComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        NgbModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
      providers: [EmpolyeeService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

This is employee.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { EmpolyeeService } from 'src/app/shared/empolyee.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-empolyee',
      templateUrl: './empolyee.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./empolyee.component.css']
      
    })
    export class EmpolyeeComponent implements OnInit {
    
      constructor(public service : EmpolyeeService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
    }
```

Guys please help! Thanks!

Comment: typos... you are using `ngModule` in two places in template... should be `ngModel`

Comment: omg.. what a bug. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I can propose to use another approach using formBuilder for your form.
In the `employee.component.html` use

```
<form [formGroup]="customGroup">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label>FULL NAME</label>
     <input formControlName="username" class="form-control">
  </div>
</form>
```

And then modify your component like

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EmpolyeeService } from 'src/app/shared/empolyee.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-empolyee',
  templateUrl: './empolyee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./empolyee.component.css']
  
})
export class EmpolyeeComponent implements OnInit {
  public customGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(public service : EmpolyeeService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
     this.customGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
       username: ['', []],
     });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

I hope, it will help you.